# Update multiple rows in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MEDICINE_REGISTRATION SET stock = @RStock WHERE id= " + Order_Datagridview.SelectedRows[0].Cells["id"].Value.ToString() + "", cn);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Order_Datagridview.Rows)
    {

        // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RStock", row.Cells["RStock"].Value);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@RStock", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Order_Datagridview.SelectedRows[0].Cells["RStock"].Value.ToString();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    }
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you want to ask a question, ask a question. Don't just dump some code and hope for the best

Comment: The code only update the first row. All I want is to update all rows in datagridview. When I click button. What should I do? What is the problem ?

Comment: There are a lots of them.

Comment: Problem 1: Your code is vulnerable for SQL Injection, due to the string concatenation in your sql command. You already use parameters, so use them ALWAYS.

Comment: _The code only update the first row_ Because you didn't do _anything_ to update rest of them since you filter your command with `Order_Datagridview.SelectedRows[0].Cells["id"].Value` on `WHERE` clause. Consider to change your logic first.

Comment: Problem 2: It's quite senseless to make a foreach loop over all rows and than use a hardcoded index to get a value from a specific row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization of the WHERE condition is outside the loop and takes always the ID of the first row, not the id of the subsequent rows. 
The parameters should be added for every single value that you take from your grid, also the id should be parameterized

Finally the parameters could be added just one time and then you could simply update their values

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE MEDICINE_REGISTRATION 
                                     SET stock = @RStock 
                                     WHERE id= @id", cn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RStock", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = 0;  

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Order_Datagridview.Rows)
    {
        // Use the row indexer here, not the fixed row at index zero
        cmd.Parameters["@RStock"].Value = row.Cells["RStock"].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["id"].Value);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    cn.Close();}
}
```

There is something also to say about the use of disposable objects like the connection and the command. These objects should be created when needed and disposed immediately after the usage. Check about the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for this pattern

Comment: Thank you sir steve. It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Order_Datagridview.SelectedRows)
{
    ..... DataGridViewRow.Cells["RStock"].Value.ToString();
}
```

?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10653406)

Comment: Ooops.. Thought I wasn´t able to comment, and it looked like the answer to me.. Hard to test without access to the db though ;)

Comment: @noontz: *A few words* describing what is wrong in the asker's code would make you answer better. Also this would prevent others to think about the answer as a comment. [As a rule, code in the answer should be accompanied with some description.]

Comment: @Tsyvarev  thx..  I´ll keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **foreach**, you are not using the DataGridViewRow, you're still using the DataGridView.Selected[0] . If you want to do this, I'd make a couple changes:

1. save the return value from ExecuteNonQuery() and MessageBox.Show that value
2. in cmd.Parameters, make sure you add the current row.
3. I would probably create a separate command for each row.

Something like this maybe:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Order_Datagridview.Rows)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE MEDICINE_REGISTRATION SET stock = " + row.cless["RStock"].Value + "  WHERE id= " + row.Cells["id"].Value.ToString() + " ", cn);

        MessageBox.Show(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());

     }

    cn.Close();
}
```

If this doesn't work for you, try grabbing the DataTable or DataView source that underlies that table and do the same thing as above.

Comment: Thank you sir. It works now :)

Comment: Thanks, Shyl! If you would mark the answer that worked for you, it helps those of us that help out. :)